# ksh remote function ssh calling another remote function

Tags: ssh, ksh

```
function test_me
{
sqlplus /nolog <<EOF
connect / as sysdba
oradebug dump systemstate 266
oradebug tracefile_name
EOF
}

function check_me 
{
ssh ${HST2} "$(typeset -f); test_me"
}

ssh ${HST1} "$(typeset -f); check_me"
```

*defination of function test_me looks good on HST1 , but gets truncates to HST2 aroung EOF, fails with unmatched <<*

**Has anyone got workaround this?**

Comment: Could you please add more information to your problem? 1. What are you trying to achieve? 2. What does actually happen? 3. Maybe a test case which fails

Comment: Are the login shells on both hosts `ksh`?

Comment: from sath I am logging on Oracle RAC cluster.. I login on first node of RAC1A, then prepare list of database on this RAC1, on various node RAC1B, RAC1C, RAC1D... then login on each of RAC1B  and connect to DB... remote function in ksh is not happy with EOF .. fails with unmatched <<

Answer (score 0):

Two things to simplify this:

1. Use the `ProxyJump` option to let `ssh` handle the connection to HST2 via HST1
2. Feed the script to `sqlplus` via standard input rather than trying to embed function definitions.

---

```
ssh -o ProxyJump=HST1 HST2 "sqlplus /nolog" <<EOF
  connect / as sysdba
  oradebug dump system state 266
  oradebug tracefile_name
EOF
```

Comment: ProxyJump doesnot help me.. as I have to run other function on HST1 to prepare list of database... based on which   I have to again login on HST1/2/3/4., to connect to database

Answer (score 0):

work around is remove EOF, but still I am not happy why EOF doesnot work..

```
function test_me    
{
echo "select sysdate from dual;" > /tmp/run.sql
sqlplus / @/tmp/run.sql
}

function check_me 
{
ssh ${HST2} "$(typeset -f); test_me"
}
ssh ${HST1} "$(typeset -f); check_me"
```